Finding unit vector of a curve in 3D space.

I have been trying to find the unit tangent vector of the vector function.
$$r(t)=\Big(e^{9t}cos(t)\Big)i+\Big(e^{9t}sin(t)\Big)j+\Big(e^{9t}\Big)k$$
I know you have to find $r'(t) by taking the derivatives of each component separately. Is that all that is required to find the direction of the tangent vector?
Then, to make it a unit tangent vector, what do you divide $r'(t)$ by?

Yes, that's all there is to it. To calculate the unit vector, just divide by the norm of the vector $r'(t)/||r'(t)||$
